# How to get current image when rotating device

Tags: android, slideshow, oncreate

I have a simple slideshow that image changes by clicking. When I rotate device, oncreate function resets slideshow and it start from image0. How to get current image?

It's my cod:

```
 private int currentImage = 0;
private int numImages = 5;
int[] imageList = { R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2, R.drawable.pic3, R.drawable.pic4, R.drawable.pic5};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    currentImage = savedInstanceState.getInt("currentImage");
    savedInstanceState.getBundle()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          currentImage++;
            currentImage = currentImage % numImages;
            image.setImageResource(imageList[currentImage]);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution

```
private int currentImage = 0;
private int numImages = 5;
int[] imageList = { R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2, R.drawable.pic3, R.drawable.pic4, R.drawable.pic5};
ImageView image;
private static final String IMAGE_COUNTER_KEY = "image_counter_key";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        currentImage = savedInstanceState.getInt(IMAGE_COUNTER_KEY);
        setCurrentImage(currentImage);
    }
    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            currentImage++;
            setCurrentImage(currentImage);
        }
    });

}
//In your activity override the onSavedInstanceState()
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(IMAGE_COUNTER_KEY, currentImage);
    }
}

//This is a helper method for setting the image based on your code
private void setCurrentImage(int imageNumber) {
        currentImage = currentImage % numImages;
        image.setImageResource(imageList[currentImage]);
}
```

Comment: I have error : java.lang.NullPointerException. in setCurrentImage method , line 2

Comment: Sorry I did not run this yet. you need to move the findview by id call to above the savedinstance state block. Code fixed check edit

Comment: Thank you. I add it in savedinstance method  befor set resource for imageView and it’s work

Comment: Check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) I beleive you can store a bundle inside the onsavedinstance state bundle. so getBundle(KEY) is doing the same as getInt(KEY) just for a different data type. It was from your code and as it currently stands it does nothing you can take it out.

Answer (score 2):

Use `onSaveInstanceState` to save your counter into `Bundle`. That bundle instance will be pushed to the `onCreate` method.

Comment: I add currentImage = savedInstanceState.getInt("currentImage");
but it has an error: Error:(38, 17) error: local variable savedInstanceState is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

Comment: U did this in which method ?

Answer (score 0):

```
// This will save state.
@ Override
onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bun){
super.onSaveInstanceState(bun);
bun.putInt("pos",currentImage);
}



//To restore state 
@Override
OnRestoreInstaneState(Bundle bun){
currentImage = bun.getInt("pos");
// set current image as pos in adapter
}
```